# Compute Galois group of extension

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, finite-fields, laurent-series

Let $C$ be an algebraically closed field with characteristic $p > 2$

What is the Galois group of the splitting field for the polynomial 
$F(X,T) = X(X+1)^p(X-1)^p - T$ over the field of formal Laurent series $C((T))$ ?

In particular, is it a cyclic group? If it doesn't, how one can show that?

Comment: I don't know about the Galois group, but the first observation I can make is that $F(X)$ is not irreducible in $K[X]$, $K=C((T))$. Unless I made a silly mistake, the recursively defined sequence $u_1=-T$, $u_{n+1}=u_n^{2p+1}-T$ converges ($T$-adically) to a zero of $F(X)$ in $K$.

Comment: I mean that if $u=\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n\in C((T))$, then $F(u)=0$ because $u^{2p+1}-T=u$.